# How do I Calculate Control Point/Handle X-Position for a Cubic Bezier Curve if I have the Formula?

Tags: javascript, curve-fitting, bezier, curve, cubic-bezier

I have a curve that adheres to the bezier formula, and then I have to back-calculate the handle positions.

[image: https://www.particleincell.com/2012/bezier-splines/]

We know that the `Po` or `Poy` are `[493.33970441 486.78826487 497.69599613 489.07543952]` for `Po`, `P1`, `P2`, `P3`, through least squares interpolation. Now I need to find the handles `Px` positions.

```
P0 = (0, 493.33970441)
P1 = (P1x, 486.78826487)
P2 = (P2x, 497.69599613)
P3 = (1, 489.07543952)
```

I might not understand correctly, but I'd like to draw the position of where the handle is on the corresponding chart.

[image]

Comment: So you have B(t) and you would like to compute the y-coordinates of P1 and P2?